# Codeigniter dynamic append input field not able to post to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using codeigniter, whereby i'm having a multiple form and one of the form is an dynamic created field. When i press Submit, all other field that are fixed can be posted, only the dynamic append input field data won't able to post over to database.

What wrong with my code for the append part?

View Code :

```
              <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="sessionID" value="<?php echo $sessionUserID;?>">
              </div>
              <div class="box-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
                        <th>Agent</th>
                        <th>Currency</th>
                        <th>Commision Rate (%)</th>
                        <th>Commision Amount</th>
                        <th><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></th>
                    </table>
                      <button type = "button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#confirm-submit" > Submit </button >
                </div>


              </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->
        </div>
        <!-- Update Confirmation Modal End -->
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var btnSwapInProgress = 0; //Verify when it was swapping in progress

        //Redemption Sub Onchange
        $(document).ready(function(){

          //Hide div
          setTimeout(function() {
            $('#alertMsg').css('display','none')
          }, 2000);
          //Company From Selection
          $("#companyFrom").on('change', function (){
              var matchvalue = $(this).val(); // this.value

              var from = document.getElementById("companyFrom"); //Select from company
              var selectedFromText = from.options[from.selectedIndex].text;
              var splitFromCurrency = selectedFromText.split("@");

              var to = document.getElementById("companyTo"); //Select to company
              var selectedToText = to.options[to.selectedIndex].text;
              var splitToCurrency = selectedToText.split("@");

              if(splitFromCurrency[1] != splitToCurrency[1] && splitToCurrency != "-Please Select-"){
                document.getElementById("companyFrom").selectedIndex = "0";
                alert("Only Order Between Same Currency Are Allow!");
                document.getElementById("userFromSelection").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("userFromBalance").style.display = "none";
                return;
              }
              else{
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Buysell_form/getUserListFrom',
                    data: { matchvalue: matchvalue },
                    type: 'post'
                }).done(function(responseData) {
                    document.getElementById("userFromSelection").style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("userFromBalance").style.display = "block";
                    $("#userFromSelection").html(responseData);
                    $('.selectCustomerFrom').select2();
                    $('#userFrom option') //Onchange Select
                     .filter(function() { return $.trim( $(this).val() ) == selectedID; })
                     .attr('selected',true).change();

                    });
              }

          });

          //User From Selection
          $("#userFromSelection").on('change', function (){
              var matchvalue = document.getElementById('userFrom').value;
              var branchID = document.getElementById('companyFrom').value;

              //Prevent same user selected
              var fromC = document.getElementById("companyFrom");
              var toC = document.getElementById("companyTo");
              var fromU = document.getElementById("userFrom");
              var toU = document.getElementById("userTo");

              if(fromC.value == toC.value && fromU.value == toU.value && toU.value != 0 && btnSwapInProgress != 1){
                document.getElementById("userFrom").selectedIndex = "0";
                $("#userFrom").select2({
                    placeholder: "-Please Select-"
                });
                alert("Same Company And Same User Not Allow To Make Order.");
              }
              else{
                  return true;
              }
          });

          //Company To Selection
            $("#companyTo").on('change', function (){
                var matchvalue = $(this).val(); // this.value

                var from = document.getElementById("companyFrom"); //Select from company
                var selectedFromText = from.options[from.selectedIndex].text;
                var splitFromCurrency = selectedFromText.split("@");

                var to = document.getElementById("companyTo"); //Select to company
                var selectedToText = to.options[to.selectedIndex].text;
                var splitToCurrency = selectedToText.split("@");

                //Verify Currency Must Same
                if(splitFromCurrency[1] != splitToCurrency[1]){
                  document.getElementById("companyTo").selectedIndex = "0";
                  alert("Only Order Between Same Currency Are Allow!");
                  document.getElementById("userToSelection").style.display = "none";
                  document.getElementById("userToBalance").style.display = "none";
                  return;
                }else{
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Buysell_form/getUserListTo',
                        data: { matchvalue: matchvalue },
                        type: 'post'
                    }).done(function(responseData) {
                        document.getElementById("userToSelection").style.display = "block";
                        document.getElementById("userToBalance").style.display = "block";
                        $("#userToSelection").html(responseData);
                        $('.selectCustomerTo').select2();
                    });
                }
            });

            //User From Selection
            $("#userToSelection").on('change', function (){
                var matchvalue = document.getElementById('userTo').value;
                var branchID = document.getElementById('companyTo').value;

                //Prevent same user selected
                var fromC = document.getElementById("companyFrom").value;
                var toC = document.getElementById("companyTo").value;
                var fromU = document.getElementById("userFrom").value;
                var toU = document.getElementById("userTo").value;

                if(fromC == toC && fromU == toU  && fromU != 0  && btnSwapInProgress != 1){
                  document.getElementById("userTo").selectedIndex = "0";
                  $("#userTo").select2({
                      placeholder: "-Please Select-"
                  });
                  alert("Same Company And Same User Not Allow To Make Order.");
                }
                else{
                  return true;
                }


            });

          //Date picker
            $('#transactionDate').datepicker({
              autoclose: true
            }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
               var maxDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
               $('#reminderDate').datepicker('setStartDate', maxDate);
           });
            $('#transactionDate').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
            $('#postDate').datepicker({
              autoclose: true
            })
            .on('changeDate', function (selected) {
               var maxDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
               $('#reminderDate').datepicker('setStartDate', maxDate);
           });
            $('#postDate').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
            $('#reminderDate').datepicker({
              autoclose: true
            })
          //Initialize Select2 Elements
          $('.select2').select2()
          $('.selectCompanyFrom').select2()
          $('.selectCompanyTo').select2()


          $('#balanceTable').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            "order": [[0, "asc"]]
          });

          //Agent
          $("#addBtn").click(function(){
              $('#mycombobox').clone().appendTo('#myloc');
          });
           var i=1;
          $('#add').click(function(){
                 i++;
                 $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'" class="dynamic-added"> '+
                 '<td><select class="form-control agent" name = "agentID[]"  style="width: 100%;" required><option value="">-Please Select- </option><?php if (!empty($agentList)) {foreach($agentList as $row) {echo $row["agent"];}}?></select></td> '+
                 '<td><select class="form-control currency" name = "currencyID[]" style="width: 100%;" required><option value="">-Please Select- </option><?php if (!empty($currencyList)) {foreach($currencyList as $row) {echo $row["currency"];}}?></select></td> '+
                 '<td><input type="number" name="commisionRate[]"  class="form-control cRate" rowNo="'+i+'"  required /></td> '+
                 '<td><input type="number" name="commisionAmount[]"  class="form-control cAmount'+i+'" required /></td> '+
                 '<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td> '+
                 '</tr>');
                 $('.agent').select2()
                 $('.currency').select2()
            });


            $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
                 var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
                 $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
            });

            $(document).on('change', '.cRate', function(){
                 var ids = $(this).attr("rowNo");
                 $('input.cAmount'+ids+'').val('000000');
            });


        });
    </script>
```

Control Code :

```
//Submit Buy Sell Order
public function insertOrder(){
  $sessionID = $this->input->post('sessionID');
  $customerCompanyFrom = $this->input->post('customerCompanyFrom');
  $selectCustomerFrom = $this->input->post('userFrom');
  $customerFromAmount = $this->input->post('customerFromAmount');
  $customerCompanyTo = $this->input->post('customerCompanyTo');
  $selectCustomerTo = $this->input->post('userTo');
  $customerToAmount = $this->input->post('customerToAmount');
  $transactionDate = $this->input->post('transactionDate');
  $postDate = $this->input->post('postDate');
  $customerBuySellType = $this->input->post('customerBuySellType');
  $customerRate = $this->input->post('customerRate');
  $companyFrom = $this->input->post('companyFrom');
  $companyTo = $this->input->post('companyTo');
  $companyBuySellType = $this->input->post('companyBuySellType');
  $companyFromAmount = $this->input->post('companyFromAmount');
  $companyToAmount = $this->input->post('companyToAmount');
  $companyRate = $this->input->post('companyRate');

  //Generate Agent Special Commission Key (Date_SessionID_selectCustomerFrom_selectCustomerTo)
  $specialKey = date("Y-m-d").$sessionID.$selectCustomerFrom.$selectCustomerTo;

  $agentID = $this->input->post('agentID');
  $currencyID = $this->input->post('currencyID');
  $commisionRate = $this->input->post('commisionRate');
  $commisionAmount = $this->input->post('commisionAmount');

  if($sessionID == ""){
    //Redirect with error message
    $data = array(
        'error_message' => 'Unauthorized Access. Please Login.'
    );
    $this->load->view('login_page', $data);
}
else if($selectCustomerFrom == null || $selectCustomerTo == null){ //If something went wrong
  //Load Client Result Page
  $dataMsg = array(
      'data1' => 'Something Missing. Please Try Again.'
  );

  $this->session->set_flashdata('message',$dataMsg);
  redirect('index.php/Branch_dashboard/buySellOrder/');
}
else{
  $transactionDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($transactionDate));
  $postDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($postDate));

  //Verify and Proceed
  $data = array(
      'CCS_BUY_SELL_CUSTOMER_FROM_COMPANY_ID' => $customerCompanyFrom,
      'CCS_BUY_SELL_CUSTOMER_FROM_USER_ID' =>  $selectCustomerFrom,
      'CCS_BUY_SELL_CUSTOMER_FROM_AMOUNT' => $customerFromAmount,
      'CCS_BUY_SELL_CUSTOMER_TO_COMPANY_ID' => $customerCompanyTo,
      'CCS_BUY_SELL_CUSTOMER_TO_USER_ID' => $selectCustomerTo,
      'CCS_BUY_SELL_CUSTOMER_TO_AMOUNT' => $customerToAmount,
      'CCS_BUY_SELL_CUSTOMER_ORDER_RATE' => $customerRate,
      'CCS_BUY_SELL_CUSTOMER_ORDER_TYPE' => $customerBuySellType,
      'CCS_BUY_SELL_TRANSACTION_DATE' => $transactionDate,
      'CCS_BUY_SELL_POST_DATE' => $postDate,
      'CCS_BUY_SELL_COMPANY_FROM_COMPANY_ID' => $companyFrom,
      'CCS_BUY_SELL_COMPANY_FROM_AMOUNT' => $companyFromAmount,
      'CCS_BUY_SELL_COMPANY_TO_COMPANY_ID' =>  $companyTo,
      'CCS_BUY_SELL_COMPANY_TO_AMOUNT' => $companyToAmount,
      'CCS_BUY_SELL_COMPANY_ORDER_RATE' => $companyRate,
      'CCS_BUY_SELL_COMPANY_ORDER_TYPE' => $companyBuySellType,
      'CCS_BUY_SELL_STATUS' => 0,
      'CCS_BUY_SELL_AGENT_COMMISSION_KEY' => $specialKey,
      'CCS_BUY_SELL_CREATED_BY' => $sessionID,
      'CCS_BUY_SELL_CREATED_DATETIME' =>  date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
  );
  $result = $this->buysell_model->registerNewOrder($data);
  if($result == TRUE){
    //Successfully Created only insert agent commission list
  foreach ($agentID as $value) { //Loop to insert all
    $data = array(
    'CCS_BUY_SELL_AGENT_COMMISSION_KEY' => $specialKey,
    'CCS_BUY_SELL_AGENT_USER_ID' => $agentID,
    'CCS_BUY_SELL_AGENT_COMMISSION_RATE' => $commisionRate,
    'CCS_BUY_SELL_AGENT_COMMISION_AMOUNT' => $commisionAmount,
    'CCS_BUY_SELL_AGENT_CURRENCY_ID' => $currencyID,
    'CCS_BUY_SELL_AGENT_COMMISSION_RATE' =>  date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
    'CCS_USER_COMPANY_COMPANY_ID' => $value);
    $this->buysell_model->registerAgentCommission($data);
  }
      //Load Client Result Page
      $dataMsg = array(
          'data1' => 'Order successfully submitted for verification.'
      );

      $this->session->set_flashdata('message',$dataMsg);
      redirect('index.php/Branch_dashboard/buySellOrder/');
  }
  else{

  }
}
}
```

Below should be the array that will be posted by the created dynamic field

```
  $agentID = $this->input->post('agentID');
      $currencyID = $this->input->post('currencyID');
      $commisionRate = $this->input->post('commisionRate');
      $commisionAmount = $this->input->post('commisionAmount');
```

Comment: This is a lot of code for us to go through and try to figure out what you are doing; it seems like a lot of it isn't relevant to your question.

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica I'm trying to let other see which part i had messed up

Comment: Your first code block is 500 lines of code, this is way too much for us to be able to narrow down ourselves. You need to try to narrow down the code to be only the part that you are having problems with. In this case, it looks like you just need to include the code you are using for the dynamically appended fields.

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica Edited

Comment: It looks like the values may be being appended to the table which is outside of the `<form>` tags

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica But the table div i had it inside the form closed. Then where should i put ?

Comment: Oh I see now; `<?php echo form_close(); ?>`. Hmm. I know you say the values don't insert into the database, but do they post to your PHP at all? Where is the function in your 2nd code block called from?

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica No, i try print_r or echo. It empty

Comment: Where did you try that?

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica Model, where i try to echo/print_r after submit but no values was show

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202215/discussion-between-marcus-tan-and-grumpy-says-reinstate-monica).